# Definite article between name and a nickname

Tags: definite-article, names

Is that true that I can use that phrasing:

"my first(given) name" the "my nickname" ?

What exactly do native speakers think when they hear such phrasing?
Is it appropriate to use as a whole nickname?

I am assuming that a nickname is a single word. I am considering something like "Ender", but I am also interested about using adjectives in the phrasing this question is about.
For example, can I use "Alex The Ender" as a nickname? Would the last word in it considered a nickname by itself?

Comment: It depends on the context but okay, an example would be `Robert "The Hulk" Banner`

Comment: Can you give more examples of specific pairs?

Comment: What exactly DO native speakers think. These are not structures.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for the corrections. How else do I call them?

Comment: You could call it a phrasing. More importantly, though, you should provide more context, telling us how you would use this. For example, if my nickname is “The Goon”, then I wouldn’t **not** say “J.R. the The Goon” –though that’s how it’s phrased in your question.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're asking.  You mean something like *"John Smith" the "Terminator"*?  The way that grooveplex put it is more common.

Comment: @J.R.♦ @stangdon I am sorry for confusing you. I meant person's given (first) name, not the full name.

Comment: @J.R.♦ I am assuming that a nickname is a single word. I am considering something like "Ender", but I am also interested about using adjectives in the phrasing this question is about.

Comment: @AlexandrG - You ought to make those clarifications in your question, not down here in the comments. And provide a couple concrete examples, like _Alexandr the Enquirer_, or whatever else you have in mind. Generally speaking, the more information you can provide in your question, the more likely you are to get detailed, helpful answers.

Comment: Not sure that this is a English language question (the topic could apply to any language). Name/nickname, regardless of how you phrase it, is a title, and you can write it any way you want. I think you are asking for writing advice...

Comment: If "the" is used, I take that to mean that "the" is part of the nickname. If the nickname doesn't contain "the", then I wouldn't use it in the person's name. Examples: George Herman "Babe" Ruth; Frank "The Big Hurt" Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

Nicknames are a form of [pseudonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudonym) and may or may not include "the" in the nickname, it depends what is intended by the nickname, also a nickname does not need to be a single word. but usually has some context or reason for a particular nickname.  For example, in many situations one's nickname becomes the name one is socially known by

> Ender
>   Top Drawer

and one's friends would simply use it as they would a given name

> Ender, do you want to join us?
>   Hey Top Drawer, what are you drinking tonight?

In UK public school, traditionally one is addressed by one's surname as a form of *nickname*.

Using "the" would be a designation to make the *nickname* more of a *title*

> He's known as The Ender.
>   "The Donald" is the new president elect in the US.

However, people would not usually use "The Ender" to directly address you, just as they would not use "The Alex", when speaking to you.

In your example, if you wrote your name as

> Alex "The Ender" Gnatyuk

your nickname would be "The Ender", however if you wrote it

> Alex "Ender" Gnatyuk
>   [Edwin Eugene "Buzz" Aldrin Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz_Aldrin)

your nickname would be considers to be "Ender", and people might say

> That guy is "Ender"
>   That guy is "Ender" Gnatyuk.